# Windows store app, Service Reference

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, service-reference

In a windows store app i have a Service Reference that looks something like this 
[image]

this is the xaml of the wsdl: http://paste2.org/B00MD3Wt

and in the generated Referece.cs file i have this

...

```
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public partial class WSDocuShareJoinWirelessClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<xxxServiceReference.IWSDocuShareJoinWireless>, xxx.ServiceReference.IWSDocuShareJoinWireless {

    public WSDocuShareJoinWirelessClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(binding, remoteAddress) {
    }
```

...

what i want to know is the binding parameter that should be used when i do this

```
private WSDocuShareJoinWirelessClient client = new WSDocuShareJoinWirelessClient(binding,remoteAddress);
```

i noticed now i also get these 2 warnings
[image]